Can noun phrases have only one word?
In Saad is now a grown man. I think that Saad is a noun phrase.
Can noun phrases have only one word?

No. Why would you think so?

It's a noun and the subject of the sentence and a proper noun. But for me, it is not a phrase (two words or more). However, there are linguists that would say it is.

ishtar answers this well. It is a troublesome fact that much of English metalanguage ('word', 'lexeme', 'phrase', 'clause', 'sentence', 'complement', 'extraposition', 'preposition' for starters) is ill-defined in that conflicting definitions are used (often usurping earlier definitions) by recognised authorities.  'Gerund' is considered best avoided for this reason by some recognised authorities. They repurpose terminology to suit their own analyses. // The other major fact one has to come to terms with is that certain usages may be considered acceptable by some authorities but not by others.

Linguists and grammarians routinely use the abbreviation np (noun phrase) as an alternative to noun. In the context of analyzing syntactic constructions, it's almost always irrelevant whether any particular np / noun happens to be a single word or several words constituting a phrase.

Can a verb phrase consist of a verb alone?  "The ice melted".

In the context of the Question, how could 'Saad is now a grown man' matter?
I think 'Saad' is a simple noun.
That or any other single word could be a noun phrase but how could that be useful here, please?
Either way, doesn't that beg the question: how could we compare 'Saad…' alone to 'Saad is now a grown man…'?
A noun phrase might have only one word, but I suggest your 'Saad… etc…' does not come close to being a useful instance…
Can you Post several more clear examples?

Ultimately, it is a matter of how one chooses to define "noun phrase". If you're taking a class, you should give whichever answer your teacher/professor seems to want. Otherwise, it doesn't seem like there's much reason to care.

Saad appears to be a name. How could a name be a phrase?

Your question has gotten a lot of response, but I'm not sure it's the kind of response you needed. To get the most useful answers, please edit to tell a bit more about what "noun phrase" means to you, and why you're asking.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't suited for ELL but belongs on EL&U, where it was originally asked! Also the site that OP actually has an account at.

A noun phrase with only one word is a noun.

In the linguistic field of generative syntax, which is where this idea of "noun phrases" is treated scientifically, there is nothing preventing a noun phrase from only containing a single noun, just as there is nothing preventing a verb phrase from only containing a single verb, and so on. In fact, the noun is the only required element of a noun phrase in the modern formulation of generative syntax.
In common (non-scientific) usage, "phrase" is understood to be a unit larger than a word but smaller than a sentence, and does not necessarily correlate to the linguistic understanding of a "phrase". By this definition, a single word could clearly not be considered a phrase.
At the end of the day, context matters. If you're talking about the syntactic components of a sentence, as in "Saad is now a grown man" is composed of the noun phrase "Saad" and the verb phrase "is now a grown man", then it is absolutely correct to call "Saad" a phrase. But if you are just talking to someone, and you misheard them and you say "Can you please repeat that phrase?" you would not be expecting to hear a single word, and if someone says something you really like and you go "Wow, that was a beautiful phrase at the end there," they would understand you to be referring to a group of multiple words.

And if you are teaching English, you tell the students that Saad is the subject of the sentence, and a proper noun. You would not call that name a noun phrase.

Many sources that should be reliable consider isolated nouns to also be valid noun phrases.
The Internet Grammar of English, UCL (university)
https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/phrases/define.htm

Noun phrases do not have to contain strings of words. In fact, they can contain just one word, such as the word "children" in "children should watch less television". ... But in a phrase-level analysis, we call children on its own a noun phrase. This is not simply a matter of terminology -- we call it a noun phrase because it can be expanded to form longer strings which are more clearly noun phrases.

[children] should watch less television
[the children] should watch less television
[the children in class 5] should watch less television
[the small children in class 5] should watch less television


Learn English, British Council
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/noun-phrases

Often a noun phrase is just a noun or a pronoun:

People like to have money.
I am tired.


Cambridge Dictionary
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/noun-phrases

A noun phrase consists of a noun or pronoun, which is called the head, and any dependent words before or after the head. Dependent words give specific information about the head.
Examples of noun phrases: [table of "dependent word(s)", "noun", "dependent word(s), ∅ added for clarity for empty cells]

∅ - love - ∅
∅ - him - ∅
the - moon - ∅
the longest - river - in the world


Analysing Language in Context, University of Nevada, Las Vegas
https://alic.sites.unlv.edu/chapter-02-02-phrases-i-noun-phrases/

... keep in mind that a noun phrase represents those structures that can fulfill a noun role. So a “noun phrase” can be a single word or multiple words.

Oxford Learners Dictionary (quoted indirectly)
https://byjus.com/english/noun-phrase/
According to the Oxford Learner’s Dictionary, a noun phrase is defined as:

a word or group of words in a sentence that behaves in the same way as a noun [...].

Mirriam-Webster
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noun%20phrase
[A little less clearly in favour of a single word noun phrase; but suggests that a noun phrase can contain no words at all]

: a phrase formed by a noun and all its modifiers and determiners
broadly: any syntactic element (such as a clause, clitic, pronoun, or zero element) with a noun's function

York Syntax, City University of New York
https://yorksyntax.commons.gc.cuny.edu/chapter-6-noun-phrases/

... some nouns can appear alone in a noun phrase, without a determiner or any other word.
These nouns include many proper nouns....
Diagrams of such phrases are about as simple as they come:



I've just added a wee bit more formatting to make it clear which bits are being cited. Nice post! +1

I don't see cited examples that are proper nouns such as "Amazon" or "Steve".
I would argue that Steve is not a clause, a verb, a preposition, a pronoun or a phrase. Steve is not an ordinary noun unlike: "children", "people", "love", or a determiner such as "him".
M-W says stev or steve, note the lowercase "s", is the abbreviation of stevadore.  It doesn't mention that Steve is also a name.
Likewise Saad is a name that is normally given to males at birth. It doesn't stand for another word, although it may have a meaning, in English we don't normally associate a person's name with its historical, or at times, archaic meaning. If we expand the proper noun to explain who Saad is then it is the phrase that follows which is the Noun Phrase "Saad is the son of Nasir”.
That's my rationale, but I am ready to be corrected.

Added an example of "Jason" as a noun phrase in the literature.
Your argument seems mostly to be "names are not nouns" and it appears there is some academic discourse supporting that: https://academic.oup.com/book/3718/chapter-abstract/145112544 . (I have not read the chapter.)

As a direct answer to your example, "Saad" sounds like a person's first name, so that is most definitely not a phrase. A person's name is a proper noun. There are some exceptions to this. Firstly, you can identify people with proper noun phrases - President Lincoln, for example. Also, there are some cultures that give phrases as names, such as the Native American Sitting Bull. But a single-word name - even if its meaning can only be expressed with multiple words (for example, the name 'John' means "God is gracious") is, as far as the English language goes, not a phrase. Any historical meaning is irrelevant when using it to identify an individual.
Regarding the broader question of can a single noun be a noun phrase, I'm not going to give you any pretentious, pseudo-intellectual answer; I'm just going to give it to you straight: no. A single noun (or any word) cannot be a noun phrase.
Webster's Dictionary gives this definition of "phrase":

a word or group of words forming a syntactic constituent with a single grammatical function

So, at first glance you might say "aha! a word or group of words! So a phrase can be a single word!". But notice the rest of the definition. It must form a syntactic constituent. In grammar, a syntactic constituent is any unit that can stand alone or be substituted as a whole within a sentence. That is where the idea of nouns as noun phrases becomes untenable. In a phrase like "John likes apples", you couldn't substitute either of the nouns with other noun phrases without changing the structure of the sentence. Some noun phrases require hyphenated words, for example. You could only directly change them with other nouns, like someone else's name besides John or another fruit like a banana.
Yes, you can have single-word sentences, but a sentence is not the same as a phrase. Sentences of single words, such as imperatives and responses to questions, rely heavily on context to understand them. For example, if you asked me what my dad's name is and I said "John" you'd understand, but if a stranger randomly came up to you and said "John" you'd be confused (unless John is your name in which case there would a different kind of confusion). Another example - if you were in danger and someone shouted "Go!" you'd know that was directed at you, but if you were watching the 100m Olympic event and heard "Go!" you'd know it was directed at someone else. These examples also belie the definition of a phrase which must have an internal structure. If we're suggesting that single words can carry a bigger meaning like a phrase then that meaning would have to be consistent.
I'm really surprised at the number of upvotes to some of the answers here but often an answer is popular because it challenges norms. And that's fine, but to paraphrase the late Douglas Adams, you can prove that black is white and that's all very clever but you'll probably get yourself killed on the next zebra crossing. Likewise, claiming a single word is a phrase and backing it up with some quotes might give you a moment of glory in the classroom as you watch your English teacher squirm, but say it in public and you'll be a laughing stock. I don't even care if this gets downvoted, I'm just glad I have the reputation to give away.

There are multi-word noun phrases that might clearly and uniquely mean John: "That tall guy", "Your brother", "The captain"; these easily replace "John" without changing the structure or even [most of] the meaning of the sentence.
